# REST API - attribute filter in media type parameters

Tags: django, rest

I want to seek some advise regarding designing REST / hipermedia API and in particular regarding implementation with [django-rest](http://django-rest-framework.org/) framework.

Instead the generic 'entity' example, I will use a more mundane 'document' entity.

**Question 1.**

```
GET /document/?[query]
```

gets a list of documents. The issue is that 'document' has few dozens of attributes and in many cases the client would care only for a few (especially in this search) - the size of the response may differ like several (up to 10) times, and also server queries may be faster. Also, I have to mention that we prefer to be schema-less.

I found samples like

```
GET /document/attr1, attr2../?[query]
```

which i find quite un-REST-ful.

Another article was suggesting to use Content-Types (in fact Accept, as it is for requests), but example was missing and still have mixed feeling. Something like:

```
Accept: application/json; attrs="attr1,attr2"
```

I am not sure if this is respecting the semantics of HTTP, and also if such use of media type parameters is appropriate (after all I want a different representation of resource - with some attributes filtered out).

**Question 2.**

If the above is more or less aceptable solution, I wonder if there is something ready in [django-rest](http://django-rest-framework.org/) regarding parsing of custom media type attributes. From what i can see in he docs, media type parameters are not separately parsed (or handled).

**Edit**

Some additional info: large part of the application is OLTP (with will not be cacheable). Architecture is JSON server with static files, JS heavy client.

**Edit 2**

Actually, I found some opinions that searches in their nature are creation of new (volatile) resource (the result), so POST method is more appropriate. This eliminates the issue under discussion. I have some problems with the created entity (result), as I don't want to have to persist it, but I think this is not compulsory. The question is what to put in 'Location' header (bogus URL, no Location header or else)? The only consistent behavior for me is exactly what I do not want to do - search POST performs the search, stores the result on server side and returns 201 with link to it. This, however, is unjustified persistence load...

Regarding browser testing, MIME type text/html may present a user friendly form for searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Architectural styles inform architectures which constrain designs which are then implemented. REST is an architectural style. You're finding it hard to design a URI, not because the implementation options are limited, but because of an architectural mismatch. Your client "wants" to maximize efficiency by reducing the size of messages. But the architectural style you've chosen (REST) [uses caching to maximize efficiency](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4), which naturally leads to larger messages (and therefore fewer resources). If your architecture doesn't use caching to maximize efficiency, it's deviating from the REST style (and potentially making a new style; Roy should do an architectural analysis of this very common style).

The solution is to either pick a different architectural style (RPC maximizes efficiency by reducing the size of messages), or influence your client to want REST because of [the quality benefits](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/net_arch_styles.htm#sec_3_5_4) it brings: scalability, simplicity, efficiency, evolvability, and user-perceived performance.

Comment: Completely right. My question overlooked to mention that caching will be disabled anyway for large part of the requests. It may be enabled for some, though, and other benefits of REST design are considered. In the particular case there is still a question for the usage of media type parameters (on the side to general architechtural principles). One more thought - shouldn't media type influence caching - how a call to the same URL will be cached if it can be json, xml or html?

Comment: To keep the set of attributes extensible, you might consider simply `GET /document/?[query]&attrs=attr1,attr2`. Specifying the attributes in the Accept header will mean you can't test the behavior with generic browsers. Regarding media types: your server needs to emit `Vary: Accept` if you're going to be returning representations in various media types for the same resource. That signals caches to store the different representations separately. On that note, I wouldn't trust every caching implementation out there to know what to do with media type parameters.

Comment: After some thoughts actually 'GET /document/attr1, attr2../?[query]' is better than 'GET /document/?[query]&attrs=attr1,attr2' with regards to caching (provided that normally each client version is using the same order; as far as I know many caching proxies ignore query string).

Comment: Caching proxies tend rather to not cache any URI with a query string in it. I'm not aware of any that cache based on the URI *as if it had no query string* component. That would quickly lead to disaster and be fixed.

Comment: After some research I really came to the point where I think it is better to solve performance problems through architecture (some unsuccessful musing at this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727620/rest-entity-hash-version-in-url-vs-etags-for-client-side-caching), rather than by 'cheap' tricks. Such queries (as in the example) should not be cacheable anyway, and also should return list of links, rather than direct values (again from the point of view of caching). I am accepting this answer as correct :)