# REST - entity (hash) version in URL vs etags for client side caching

Tags: rest, caching

I am designing a REST API and lately I put some thought on how to make most of caching for dynamic content (after the response that I got on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627551/rest-api-attribute-filter-in-media-type-parameters)), while respecting the principles of HTTP (and thus REST).

Obviously the canonical solution (at least in my understanding) is to use etags, but this will not decrease the number of requests in any way, just the size.

I was thinking of embedding a version in the URL (it will be server produced, based on the actual content - be it serial number or some hash). I will explain the scheme and the user scenario and how I think it will help, and then ask my questions.

**Setup**

```
GET /entity/{id}/
```

returns temporary redirect to `/entity/{id}/{current_version}` and no-cache headers.

```
GET /entity/{latest_version}/
```

returns OK response with cache forever.

```
GET /entity/{old_version}/
```

returns 410 Gone (I don't want to actually keep old versions).

GET /entity/?[query]

is some search that returns a list of links to *current versions* of result entities. No cache.

**Use scenario and how I think it would help**

User application (AJAX) will always start with some kind of query, then it has to pull the descriptions of entities. Since it is expected that changes for a single client result set will not be very dynamic, it seems good idea to use the above scheme and client pull fresh results from the query every time, but if most of the entities did not change since last visit, they will be already cached in browser. If this hypothesis is true, this will lead to significant decrease in the number of requests, as well as total size.

Using etags would result in much simpler URI scheme, but probably more complicated and heavy server side implementation.

**Notes and questions**

**1**
I know somebody will propose that `/entity/{id}/` should be a collection that returns list versions, but versions are not actually stored, useful or desired. It is more a synonym for the latest one. My question here is if somebody sees any problem with that, besides general principles. This is protected API, I do not care about SEO in this case and it is transparent for client. Actually, as API will be more or less hyperlinked, it is not expected to actually call /entity/{id}/ directly normally, but use whatever results returns. It can be used, for example for context free links.

**2**
I have some doubts for 410 Gone for old versions. On one hand this version is not available anymore and clients should not be accessing it anyway. On the other hand, if client asks for it after all (for whatever reason), it may make sense to return permanent redirect to /entity/{id}/ (probably better that temporary redirect to current version).

**3**
Speaking of redirects. 301 is cemented for permanent redirect, but is 302 the best choice for temporary? Most important is browser support (it will be AJAX).

**4**
Of course, the main issue is the usage of URLs instead of etags for caching (hoping on the browser caches). If somebody has real experience under high load (relative to servers capabilities, cough), I will appreciate sharing it.

**Additional notes**

After some more research there is an issue with versioned resources and it is propagation of updates for linked resources. There are two options:

1. Link a specific version of the resource. This means that server side logic will be heavy and cumbersome, as updates have to be propagated for linked resources through reverse links;
2. Link the /latest/ version. This means that even if both resource and linked resourced concrete versions are cached locally, clients (browsers) will have to make a request to /latest/ in order to 'check' latest version of a linked resource. Of course it is a small request (only redirect) and if resource didn't change location is already cached. One problem may be that resources are often pulled from such links (in opposite to query result to particular version). Another (much worse) problem is that actually old version of the resource is linking the newest version of another - it can be data inconsistency (i.e. somebody edited document and also changed a linked attachment - client will have old version of the document and new one for the attachment).

Both options are unsatisfactory. In this light caching of dynamic data is possible only for 'leaf' level resources - ones that do not link to any other, bust just have direct attribute values.

**Final notes**

After research and discussions, versioned resources are not the brightest idea as general architecture. After measurement and given the opportunity, something can be retrofitted in a canonical API for 'plain' resources. I would accept Roysvork's comment (' It is my opinion that the reason this is difficult is that it is not really a very good idea.') as solution, if it was a separate answer :)

Comment: Have you looked into CacheCow? This will do all the hard work for you ... you only need set it up.

http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/introducing-cachecow-http-caching.html

I also have a post about using Cache cow from the browser here: http://roysvork.wordpress.com/

Comment: The issue is not about implementing particular caching strategy, but designing the strategy. Specifically maximizing browser caching with cache-forever (and significantly decreasing the number of requests - even conditional requests would be costly enough - consider authentication and authorization for example).

Comment: I see... it is an interesting proposal. However you are talking about temporary redirects will this not defeat the point of avoiding the conditional requests in the first place?

Comment: This is only in the case of resources linked by 'latest' version - the idea is to try to minimize these. The bulk of the resources should be linked by concrete version as a result from query. As the resources for separate client are expected to change occasionally, most of the resources that appear in search should stay in a version that is already cached.

Comment: Additionally, using Etags or LastChanged does not resolve the server side complexity and cost of accessing changes in linked resources. It is only because of the general architecture that this problem does not stand out.

Comment: Yes I see... sorry I cannot be more helpful. It is my opinion that the reason this is difficult is that it is not really a very good idea. I suggest you stick with the tried and tested approach.

Comment: Probably you are right. And the truth is that we have to measure. Actually versioned resources should be easy to extend over a canonical  API, given a properly hyperlinked API (in the sense of impact to client code), so probably it is better bet to start with clean API, load test, measure and act accordingly.

Comment: It was a good thought though! I like to see people thinking outside the box.

Comment: I was thinking this was a great design, until I read "I don't want to actually keep old versions". Really, if you just want cache control, why not using [`If-None-Match`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26)? This is already implemented in a lot of servers, proxies, reverse proxies, and libraries.

Comment: Ah OK, I just saw your comment on your need to reference a concrete revision. However, you should try to mix both approaches together.